# Jenkins: Unable to launch agent on K8 cluster

Tags: java, kubernetes, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, kubernetes-helm

Trying to launch jenkins agent on k8 cluster using kubernetes plugin. The error message is unclear as shown below. Any idea how to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Jenkins Version: 2.443

```
WARNING o.c.j.p.k.KubernetesLauncher#launch: Kubernetes returned unhandled HTTP code -1 null
        .
        .
        .
        .
        
Caused: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: An error has occurred.
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:129)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:122)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.CreateOnlyResourceOperation.create(CreateOnlyResourceOperation.java:44)
        at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesLauncher.launch(KubernetesLauncher.java:133)
        at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.lambda$_connect$0(SlaveComputer.java:297)
        at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$2.call(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:80)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```